# Load json file to neo4j causal cluster in google cloud

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, neo4j, cloud

I have a huge json file (1 gb) data and I want to insert it into Neo4j database in google cloud platform. I have uploaded my json file in /var/lib/neo4j/import directory and I tried to use the following cypher code to create my nodes in neo4j. Unfortunately I receive the following error.

```
call apoc.load.json('file:///nov.json') yield value 
unwind value as val
merge(a:Article{title:val.title,  text:val.text, url:val.url })
```

Following error

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url or key file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/nov.json as json: /var/lib/neo4j/import/nov.json (No such file or directory)
```

I would like to know what is the best way to load this json file into neo4j database.

Comment: Clearly it doesn't see the file in that directory, can you please post the output of `ls -la /var/lib/neo4j/import/` ?

Answer (score 1):

Once `apoc.import.file.enabled=true` is enabled, imports should use (file) URLs relative to the `dbms.directories.import` directory.

I believe the URL should be `file://nov.json` (and not the absolute path `file:///nov.json`).